# Reprovision missing TFSReports for TFS 2015 projects after upgrade

Tags: reporting-services, tfs-2015

We've upgraded and moved a TFS 2013 RTM server to TFS 2015.1, but now the reports are missing in the Reporting server. The Tfs2010OlapReportDS and
Tfs2010ReportDS are visible in the SQL Server Reporting Services Home screen, but the TfsReports folder and underlying folders/reports for project collections and projects are not available. If you create a new team project in the server, its reports are created properly.

Does anyone know how I can reprovision the reports in TFS 2015 for the existing projects? I found [this link on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462695(v=VS.100).aspx?tduid=(09f5f5941bab4cf3058267b3c2a84919)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-pCJHrxBSZQizf277l5QagA)()#Anchor_1), but can't find how I can do this in TFS 2015.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you configure report service during the upgrade interface or after the upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround, by reconfiguring the reporting service from the TFS administration console and pointing it to a DB server that has the ReportsDB and its Temp DB.